# What should i use to store multiple images?

Tags: java, android

What should i use to store multiple images that i retrieve from for loop? array or list? Is there any example functions that i can use? Below is my example for loop where i get my data.

```
  JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());
        JSONArray uniObject = mainObject.getJSONArray("result");
        for(int i = 0; i < uniObject.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject rowObject = uniObject.getJSONObject(i);
 co.img1 = ipAddress +"img/store/" + rowObject.getString("store_banner");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ArrayList<>();` It's away more flexible than the normal array;